# MySql greater than with group by

Tags: mysql

I have following table:

```
account(id, balance, bank_branch)
```

I want to select all accounts where account balance is greater then average balance in its bank_branch

I've tried

```
Select id from account where balance > (SELECT avg(balance) from account group by bank_branch)
```

but the subquery returns more than one row so it doesn't work.

How can I achieve something like that?

EDIT: sample data:

```
account(1, 200, A)
account(2, 400, A)
account(3, 100, B)
account(4, 300, B)

account 1,2 are in same branch - A
account 3,4 are in same branch - B

avg balance of branch A = 300
avg balance of branch B = 200

hence the output of my query should be 2,4 as
account 2 balance is 400 which is > 300(avg of A)
and account 4 balance is 300 which is > 200(avg of B)
```

Comment: see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A corelated subquery is a option

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 account_out.id
FROM 
 account account_out
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      1
    FROM 
     account account_in   
    GROUP BY 
     account_in.bank_branch
    HAVING account_out.balance > AVG(account_in.balance) 
  );
```

**Result**

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
| 4   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhWKL7iMKeAWjx4NuMGtuC/2)

Also a other option to avoid the use of a corelated subquery is using a self join

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 account.id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        account.bank_branch
      , AVG(account.balance) AS avg_balance
    FROM 
     account   
    GROUP BY 
     account.bank_branch
) AS account_filter
INNER JOIN 
  account
ON
    account_filter.bank_branch = account.bank_branch
  AND
    account_filter.avg_balance < account.balance
```

**Result**

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
| 4   |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhWKL7iMKeAWjx4NuMGtuC/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a300bd0423720866d1d6c99ca2a6a097)**

```
 SELECT id from account where balance > ANY(SELECT avg(balance) FROM account
     GROUP BY bank_branch)
```

OUTPUT:

```
id
2
4
```

Comment: But it's ommiting the fact that balance should be greater then avg balance **in its bank_branch** your answer takes the avg(balance) of all branches

Comment: @JakubLedwon, it would be great if you add some sample data and your expected output in your question

Comment: *"But it's ommiting the fact that balance should be greater then avg balance in its bank_branch your answer takes the avg(balance) of all branches "* @JakubLedwon based on the available infromation in the question which was not alot fa06 made a (very) decent educated guess for better answers see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @fa06 You are right my question wasn't very informative sorry, I've added some data

Comment: @JakubLedwon, I've edited according to your requirement you can check now

Comment: i would upvote again if i could as i always forgot about `ANY` or `ALL` SQL keywords as your SQL is more easy to read then a corelated subquery or a self join

Answer (score 0):

Select id from account where balance in (SELECT avg(balance) from account group by bank_branch)

Comment: Query does not make alot of sense, this query would return id's where the balance is **equal** to the AVG